# In Angular 7, where do I find the HttpClient library?

Tags: angular, rest, httpclient

I'm using Angular 7.  I have a very simple application so far that just reads a list of books from an endpoint.  The src/app/app.component.ts file looks like

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';
  books;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    http.get('http://localhost:3000/books.json')
      .subscribe(res => this.books = res.json());
  }
}
```

However when I start up my app using "ng serve," I get the error

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(2,10): error TS2305: Module '"/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/getting_started/home-library/node_modules/@angular/http/http"' has no exported member 'HttpClient'.
```

Where am I supposed to import my HttpClient library from?

Comment: In order to use `HttpClient` you also need to import `HttpClientModule` also in your `app.module.ts`. Otherwise there will be a provider error.Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following import  `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';.`

Answer (score 0):

The HttpClient library can be imported from `import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to import `HttpClientModule` in your `app.module.ts` from `@angular/common/http` like below in order to use `HttpClient`

   `import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http'.`
2. Then include `HttpClientModule` in the `imports` array of `@NgModule` in `app.module.ts`
3. Then in your service class you need to import `HttpClient` like below -

   `import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http'`

Older `Http` client/`HttpModule` has been removed in the recent versions of Angular.

Answer (score -1):

I was blocked from the same error as you.

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/http/src/http_module.d.ts(11,10): error TS2305: Module '"C:/PROIECTE/SfaBackend-Angular/Taswik.Core/ClientApp/node_modules/@angular/http/src/http"' has no exported member 'HttpClient'.
```

I made all the changes, but they did not work, not before change inside
`node_modules/@angular/http/src/http.d.ts/HttpClient`  every `Http` with `HttpClient` and run `ng serve`

I hope it will work for you too.